# How to check that the firebase RTDB date equal to the date i have given through the date picker

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart, firebase-realtime-database

[This is the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yBsn.png)  Here is the code that I have taken the count of Orders that which the "IsDelivered" value is true and false separately.

```
**dasboard.dart.**

import 'package:easyway/future.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';


class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  static DateTime _date;
  Dashboard({this.app});
  final FirebaseApp app;

  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  final _referenceData = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
      .child('orders')
      .orderByChild('isDelivered');
 Query dataRef;
  Map myList = {};
  String name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    dataRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('orders').orderByChild(
            'deliveryDate');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(dataRef);
    // Widget buildorder({Map orders,int count}){
    //   return Center(child: Text(orders['isDelivered'].toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),));
    // }
    // final ref = _referenceData.reference();
    var _height = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .height;
    var _width = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DashBoard", style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black
        ),),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(29.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                showDatePicker(context: context,
                    initialDate: Dashboard._date == null
                        ? DateTime.now()
                        : Dashboard._date,
                    firstDate: DateTime(2018),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2022)
                ).then((value) {
                  setState(() {

                    Dashboard._date = value;
                  });
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                height: _height * .15,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black38,
                        blurRadius: 3,
                        spreadRadius: 3,
                        offset: Offset(4.0, 4.0),
                      )
                    ]
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),

                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Text(
                    Dashboard._date == null ? DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd().format(
                        DateTime.now()).toString() : DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd()
                        .format(Dashboard._date)
                        .toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 29, right: 14),
            child: Text("Production Efficiency & Order Taken", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 23, fontFamily: 'Lato'
            ),),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: _height * .3,
                  width: _width * .4,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black38,
                        blurRadius: 2,
                        spreadRadius: 2,
                        offset: Offset(4.0, 4.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Total Hours", style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 26,
                          color: Colors.lightBlue,
                          fontFamily: 'Lato'),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20,),
                      Text("25", style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        indent: _height / 13,
                        endIndent: _width / 8,
                        thickness: 4,
                      ),
                      Text("30", style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 25,),
                Container(
                  height: _height * .3,
                  width: _width * .4,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black38,
                          blurRadius: 2,
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                          offset: Offset(4.0, 4.0),
                        )
                      ]
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 29, right: 29, top: 20, bottom: 29),
            child: Dashboard._date == null ?SampleClass(
              height: _height*.35,
              length: 'Delivered :',
              length1: "Postponed :",
              source: databaseRef.equalTo(true).once(),
              source1: databaseRef.equalTo(false).once(),
            ):Container()
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

**future.dart.**

import 'package:easyway/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class SampleClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final double height;
  final String length;
  final Future<DataSnapshot> source;
  final String length1;
  final Future<DataSnapshot> source1;

  const SampleClass({Key key,this.height,this.length,this.source,this.length1,this.source1}):super(key:key);
  @override
  _SampleClassState createState() => _SampleClassState();
}

class _SampleClassState extends State<SampleClass> {
  Dashboard date = Dashboard();
  final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
      .child('orders')
      .orderByChild('isDelivered');
  final datarF = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('orders').orderByChild('deliveryDate');
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _future = Firebase.initializeApp();
 static List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> lists = [];
  static Widget future({String length,Future<DataSnapshot> source}){
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: source,
      builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          lists.clear();
          Map<dynamic,dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
          values.forEach((key, value) {
            lists.add(values);
          });
          return Container(
            child: Text(length+lists.length.toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          );
        }else{
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: widget.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Colors.blue,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black38,
                blurRadius: 3,
                spreadRadius: 3,
                offset: Offset(4.0, 4.0),
              )
            ]
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            future(
                length: widget.length,
                source: widget.source,
            ),
            future(
              length: widget.length1,
              source: widget.source1,
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: datarF.equalTo("17/03/2021").once(),
              builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  lists.clear();
                  Map<dynamic,dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
                  values.forEach((key, value) {
                   if(values!=null){
                     lists.add(values);
                   }else{
                     lists.length = 0;
                   }
                  });
                  return Text(values['deliveryDate'].toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);
                }else{
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

How to check that the firebase RTDB date equal to the date I have given through the date picker and I want to take the count of orders "isDElivered" value that was equal to the date chosen through the date picker.

How do I get the solution please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Realtime database doesn't supports multiple equalTo query. Therefore necessary to filter list by second parameter by itself. Try to get list of delivered orders and filter it by `where` function. Something like this:

```
Widget _buildDeliveredOrdersWidget(DateTime date) {
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child('orders')
      .orderByChild('isDelivered')
      .equalTo(true)
      .once()
      .then((value) => filterByDate(value.value, date));

  return FutureBuilder(
    future: ref,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(
          "Found ${snapshot.data.length} delivered orders for $date",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        );
      } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    },
  );
}

List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> filterByDate(
        List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> orders, DateTime date) =>
    orders.where((element) => element['deliveryDate'] == date).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable response, I have tried this too but that too not getting, the snapshot was taking null. Is there any way to solve this? @ Ivan Krivtsov

Comment: @JithinKrishna There are any errors in logs?

Comment: Not showing any errors .when i run the pgm I got the circular progress.And i print the snapshot.data and i got a null value.

Comment: Format selected date (to format that in db) to string befor comparing with element['deliveryDate']. Or parse element['deliveryDate'] to DateTime and compare result with selected date.